# Magento 2.4.5 catalog category product indexing takes too long

Tags: php, magento, mariadb, magento2.4

I am having trouble debugging problem with catalog category product indexer. Basically I have two root categories, only one is active for one store view.
Totally between 20k and 90k products.
Problem appears when I add empty category as subcategory of root and reindexing takes like 30+ mins and that doesn't seem ok.

Environment: Magento 2.4.5, MariaDB 10.4.12, nginx 1.18, elasticsearch 7.17.0, PHP 8.1.0.

Note: I found solution on setting these in mariadb config
optimizer_switch=rowid_filter=off
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity=1

But I did help on one place, but on another with same environment didn't so I am not sure what else could I try.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Setting optimizer_switch=rowid_filter=off and optimizer_use_condition_selectivity=1 bought Category Products index time down from 20mins to 9secs